# how to create a fullscreen webview with Android Studio with no title bar

Tags: android

**How to create a full screen webview  with Android Studio with no title bar?
I am try to build a webview with android studio.**

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your current attempt, and a detailed description of the problems you're having.

Answer (score 1):

Create a full screen activity very easy by Android Studio:

1. `Right` click on your project where you wanna to create the `Activity`(or type `cmd + N`);
2. On the top menu, choose `New`,Then you will see `Activity` item;
3. Choose `Activity` item to display `Fullscreen Activity`. Just click to create a full screen activity
4. On the new Activity, you can do anything, e.g. put your [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

[image]